# Can you call a function using the value of a variable as the function name?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to call a function of a class using the value of a variable as the function name, and wondered if that is actually possible.

Say I have the following:

```
    let functionArray = [
      {fctn1 : 'sayHello'},
      {fctn2 : 'sayGoodbye'}
    ];

    module.exports = class subItem extends Item {
      constructor(parent, option) {
        if (!option) return;
        super(parent, option);
        // Below is what I am trying to do. 
        // trying to call 'this.sayHello()'

        this.[functionArray.fctn1];
      }
      sayHello(){ console.log('hello'); }
      sayGoodbye(){ console.log('goodbye'); }
    }
```

How would I call a function of an object/class using the value of a variable as the function name?  I appreciate it may sound an odd thing to do but hopefully someone might know :)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `()` to call function and also you need to remove dot before `[]`:

```
this[functionArray.fctn1]();
```

Explanation: to access properties of object (methods are also properties) you can use dot notation or square brackets:

```
this.sayHello();
// or
this['sayHello']();
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, when getting an object's property using a string, you don't need the `.`, instead the syntax is just `object['string']`. Second to call the function you need to include parenthesis `()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

For global functions:

```
window["functionName"](arguments);
```

In case of namespaced function:

```
window["My"]["Namespace"]["functionName"](arguments);
```